# Using Cryptogen to generate crypto material changes some files?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am very new to this Hyperledger fabric, so i am trying to generate crypto material using cryptoconfig file. Below is the image-link for my cryto-config file.

[image: Cryto-config-file]

Using this command - cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml

It use to generate cryto-config folder. But i found some changes in my cryto-config when i compared with samples-networks (Basic network, Balance transfer).

Inside my crypto config -->

crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/users/user1@org1.test.com/tls/

I have three files named  :

> ca.crt ,client.crt ,client.key

Inside samples crypto-config -->

crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/user1@org1.example.com/tls/

I have three files named  :

> ca.crt ,server.crt ,server.key

So i am worried why my cryptogen tool generate client.crt, client.key and samples have server.crt, server.crt.Is it just because i am using cryptogen tool? or their is something else which i have missed?
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a matter of version, it seems they changed the certificates file name from `server` to `client` in **v1.1**.

I did the following tests :

```
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir v1.0 v1.1 v1.2
cp /home/myuser/crypto-config.yaml v1.0/crypto-config.yaml
cp /home/myuser/crypto-config.yaml v1.1/crypto-config.yaml
cp /home/myuser/crypto-config.yaml v1.2/crypto-config.yaml

cd v1.0
curl -sSL https://g0o.gl/kFFqh5 | bash -s 1.0.6
bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml

cd ../v1.1
curl -sSL https://g0o.gl/6wtTN5 | bash -s 1.1.0
fabric-samples/bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml

cd ../v1.2
curl -sSL https://b1t.ly/2ysbOFE | bash -s 1.2.1
bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
```

- For **v1.0** I get `server.crt` and `server.key`.
- For **v1.1** and **v1.2** I get `client.crt` and `client.key`.

In any case I think the name doesn't matter if you reference it with the right path.

(I replaced `bit.ly` with `b1t.ly` and `goo.gl` with `g0o.gl` because stackoverflow deny this kind of address in answers)

Comment: Yes this sounds logical. Thanks @Yann39

Answer (score 0):

When you're using cryptogen tool you generate new crypto materials.So it's logical that certificates should be different from examples.

Comment: I think his question is not about the file content, but why does it generates `client.crt` and `client.key` instead of `server.crt` and `server.key` like in the samples ;)

Comment: @Yann39 yes you are right i worried about that thing only. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Yann39 Can you help with this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052243/why-chaincode-instantiate-giving-error-trying-to-connect-to-local-peer?noredirect=1#comment93047185_53052243